# Unequal Height of two Div, using HTML& CSS only

Tags: html, css

There are two vertical divs, left side div is not equal in height to right div, while I have used some position just to create slider effect, I think that is creating issue. Any help will be appreciated.

code is below:

```
    <!Doctype HTML>
<HTML lang="en">
<head>
<Title>Slider Test</Title>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.banner{
    background-color:#deebf5;
    padding:5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    min-height:100px;
}
.topology{
    width:3%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#99ccff;
}
.gridarea{
    width:97%;
    float:left;
}
.slider{
    position:relative;
}
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0; /* 0 width - changes this with JavaScript */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 105;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #99ccff;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sliderButton{
    background-color:#7070db;
    padding:12px 15px;
    color:#fff;
    width:100%;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.textTopology {
    margin:0px 15px;
    color:#9999e6;
    font-size:1.5em;
    font-weight:500;
}
.gridContent{
    margin:10px 0px;
    border-left: 1px solid #eef;
    border-right: 1px solid #eef;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eef;
}
</style>
<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "300px";
}
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

</div><!-- /nav.row end-->
<div class="banner row"> <!--   Main Banner starts   -->
    <p>Banner goes here</p>
</div> <!-- / Main banner ends here-->
<div class="row asd">   
    <div class="topology">
        <div class="slider" >
        <p class="sliderButton pull-right" role="button" onclick="openNav()">&gt;&gt;</p>
        <div class="textTopology">
            <p>S</p>
            <p>L</p>
            <p>I</p>
            <p>D</p>
            <p>E</p>
            <p>R</p>
        </div>
        <div  class="sidenav" id="mySidenav">
          <p class="sliderButton" onclick="closeNav()">List <span class="pull-right">&lt;&lt;</span></p>
            <div>
                <p>Will display Some content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="gridarea">
        <div> <!-- Grid Rows starts here-->
            <div class="gridContent col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et stet persius iuvaret eam, habemus adipiscing vis et. Ei clita quidam fastidii usu. Id vel tritani adipisci, usu ad recusabo philosophia, in nonumy tempor conceptam eam. Qui solet alienum efficiendi ea, id vis augue lobortis efficiantur, quo et audiam similique. Eos te vocent ponderum, nemore reformidans te cum, pri ei alii minimum adipisci.
                Vivendum qualisque mea id, nihil deserunt ut pri, pri an falli veniam timeam. Sea ei illud deterruisset, discere facilisi necessitatibus in quo, vel everti electram ex. Ad solet eligendi cum. Duo ea ferri offendit, eu brute tractatos eos. Eu nec sint habeo aeterno, soleat similique reprimique cum ut, duo mundi iisque voluptaria an.
                Mea eleifend scriptorem delicatissimi eu. An cum quem constituto vituperatoribus, ceteros salutatus cu eum. Nec eu illud delicatissimi. Bonorum ornatus salutatus mel et. Vis soluta graecis incorrupte ad, modus movet pri ad.
                Vis ea indoctum gubergren aliquando, ad nulla ubique mei. Tale dolorum adversarium an eum, ea duo tempor tacimates temporibus, vim dolor invenire no. Ad eam agam doctus fierent, nec at nulla nostrud nominavi. Ex platonem consulatu pertinacia vim. Cum consul adolescens interesset eu. Denique albucius menandri ea nam.
                Nec utinam lobortis ex. Sea singulis urbanitas interesset ne, in est dolorem iracundia intellegebat. Aliquando persecuti scriptorem pri ex, eu everti aperiri eos. Ne per integre rationibus. Eu eum sanctus laboramus reprehendunt, ex mel dicat adolescens deterruisset.</p>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div> <!-- Grid Rows starts here-->
            <div class="gridContent col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et stet persius iuvaret eam, habemus adipiscing vis et. Ei clita quidam fastidii usu. Id vel tritani adipisci, usu ad recusabo philosophia, in nonumy tempor conceptam eam. Qui solet alienum efficiendi ea, id vis augue lobortis efficiantur, quo et audiam similique. Eos te vocent ponderum, nemore reformidans te cum, pri ei alii minimum adipisci.
                Vivendum qualisque mea id, nihil deserunt ut pri, pri an falli veniam timeam. Sea ei illud deterruisset, discere facilisi necessitatibus in quo, vel everti electram ex. Ad solet eligendi cum. Duo ea ferri offendit, eu brute tractatos eos. Eu nec sint habeo aeterno, soleat similique reprimique cum ut, duo mundi iisque voluptaria an.
                Mea eleifend scriptorem delicatissimi eu. An cum quem constituto vituperatoribus, ceteros salutatus cu eum. Nec eu illud delicatissimi. Bonorum ornatus salutatus mel et. Vis soluta graecis incorrupte ad, modus movet pri ad.
                Vis ea indoctum gubergren aliquando, ad nulla ubique mei. Tale dolorum adversarium an eum, ea duo tempor tacimates temporibus, vim dolor invenire no. Ad eam agam doctus fierent, nec at nulla nostrud nominavi. Ex platonem consulatu pertinacia vim. Cum consul adolescens interesset eu. Denique albucius menandri ea nam.
                Nec utinam lobortis ex. Sea singulis urbanitas interesset ne, in est dolorem iracundia intellegebat. Aliquando persecuti scriptorem pri ex, eu everti aperiri eos. Ne per integre rationibus. Eu eum sanctus laboramus reprehendunt, ex mel dicat adolescens deterruisset.</p>
            </div>      
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="gridContent col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et stet persius iuvaret eam, habemus adipiscing vis et. Ei clita quidam fastidii usu. Id vel tritani adipisci, usu ad recusabo philosophia, in nonumy tempor conceptam eam. Qui solet alienum efficiendi ea, id vis augue lobortis efficiantur, quo et audiam similique. Eos te vocent ponderum, nemore reformidans te cum, pri ei alii minimum adipisci.
                Vivendum qualisque mea id, nihil deserunt ut pri, pri an falli veniam timeam. Sea ei illud deterruisset, discere facilisi necessitatibus in quo, vel everti electram ex. Ad solet eligendi cum. Duo ea ferri offendit, eu brute tractatos eos. Eu nec sint habeo aeterno, soleat similique reprimique cum ut, duo mundi iisque voluptaria an.
                Mea eleifend scriptorem delicatissimi eu. An cum quem constituto vituperatoribus, ceteros salutatus cu eum. Nec eu illud delicatissimi. Bonorum ornatus salutatus mel et. Vis soluta graecis incorrupte ad, modus movet pri ad.
                Vis ea indoctum gubergren aliquando, ad nulla ubique mei. Tale dolorum adversarium an eum, ea duo tempor tacimates temporibus, vim dolor invenire no. Ad eam agam doctus fierent, nec at nulla nostrud nominavi. Ex platonem consulatu pertinacia vim. Cum consul adolescens interesset eu. Denique albucius menandri ea nam.
                Nec utinam lobortis ex. Sea singulis urbanitas interesset ne, in est dolorem iracundia intellegebat. Aliquando persecuti scriptorem pri ex, eu everti aperiri eos. Ne per integre rationibus. Eu eum sanctus laboramus reprehendunt, ex mel dicat adolescens deterruisset.</p>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div> <div class="clearfix"></div><!--Right side contents, all grid areas-->
</div> <!-- /Topology + Grid contents ends here -->
</div> <!-- /Main.container ends here which is holding entire divs-->
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Do you mean that the text on the right is not that the top? it's fine when I run it

Comment: Do you mean that the slider content is not the same height as the collapsed slider?

Comment: To clarify, I just want to show the left div with background color equal in height as of left side contents div(Lorum Ipsum).

Comment: The first one, or all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox to the rescue! Using the `flex` [shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex): `flex-grow` `flex-shrink` `flex-basis`.

```css
/* First, we're setting the containing element as flex */
.row.asd {
  display: flex;
}

/* Then, setting the "sidebar" to a maximum of 40px,
   and making sure it doesn't shrink! */
.topology {
  flex: 1 0 40px;
  background-color: #99ccff;
}

/* And giving the content the rest of the width with flex-basis auto */
.gridarea {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row asd">
  <div class="topology">
    m
  </div>
  <div class="gridarea">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et stet persius iuvaret eam, habemus adipiscing vis et. Ei clita quidam fastidii usu. Id vel tritani adipisci, usu ad recusabo philosophia, in nonumy tempor conceptam eam. Qui solet alienum efficiendi ea, id vis augue lobortis efficiantur, quo et audiam similique. Eos te vocent ponderum, nemore reformidans te cum, pri ei alii minimum adipisci. Vivendum qualisque mea id, nihil deserunt ut pri, pri an falli veniam timeam. Sea ei illud deterruisset, discere facilisi necessitatibus in quo, vel everti electram ex. Ad solet eligendi cum. Duo ea ferri offendit, eu brute tractatos eos. Eu nec sint habeo aeterno, soleat similique reprimique cum ut, duo mundi iisque voluptaria an. Mea eleifend scriptorem delicatissimi eu. An cum quem constituto vituperatoribus, ceteros salutatus cu eum. Nec eu illud delicatissimi. Bonorum ornatus salutatus mel et. Vis soluta graecis incorrupte ad, modus movet pri ad. Vis ea indoctum gubergren aliquando, ad nulla ubique mei. Tale dolorum adversarium an eum, ea duo tempor tacimates temporibus, vim dolor invenire no. Ad eam agam doctus fierent, nec at nulla nostrud nominavi. Ex platonem consulatu pertinacia vim. Cum consul adolescens interesset eu. Denique albucius menandri ea nam. Nec utinam lobortis ex. Sea singulis urbanitas interesset ne, in est dolorem iracundia intellegebat. Aliquando persecuti scriptorem pri ex, eu everti aperiri eos. Ne per integre rationibus. Eu eum sanctus laboramus reprehendunt, ex mel dicat adolescens deterruisset.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et stet persius iuvaret eam, habemus adipiscing vis et. Ei clita quidam fastidii usu. Id vel tritani adipisci, usu ad recusabo philosophia, in nonumy tempor conceptam eam. Qui solet alienum efficiendi ea, id vis augue lobortis efficiantur, quo et audiam similique. Eos te vocent ponderum, nemore reformidans te cum, pri ei alii minimum adipisci. Vivendum qualisque mea id, nihil deserunt ut pri, pri an falli veniam timeam. Sea ei illud deterruisset, discere facilisi necessitatibus in quo, vel everti electram ex. Ad solet eligendi cum. Duo ea ferri offendit, eu brute tractatos eos. Eu nec sint habeo aeterno, soleat similique reprimique cum ut, duo mundi iisque voluptaria an. Mea eleifend scriptorem delicatissimi eu. An cum quem constituto vituperatoribus, ceteros salutatus cu eum. Nec eu illud delicatissimi. Bonorum ornatus salutatus mel et. Vis soluta graecis incorrupte ad, modus movet pri ad. Vis ea indoctum gubergren aliquando, ad nulla ubique mei. Tale dolorum adversarium an eum, ea duo tempor tacimates temporibus, vim dolor invenire no. Ad eam agam doctus fierent, nec at nulla nostrud nominavi. Ex platonem consulatu pertinacia vim. Cum consul adolescens interesset eu. Denique albucius menandri ea nam. Nec utinam lobortis ex. Sea singulis urbanitas interesset ne, in est dolorem iracundia intellegebat. Aliquando persecuti scriptorem pri ex, eu everti aperiri eos. Ne per integre rationibus. Eu eum sanctus laboramus reprehendunt, ex mel dicat adolescens deterruisset.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Complete example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/pnhywgg0/

Comment: Thank you so muchhhh......!!

One more help required, like as per your solution in the jsfiddle when you click on >> sign on the slider t is opening the but the chopped of in the size, can we also make it as the same height as of the slider div?